# Popular FTP clients failed to autodetect that VSFTPD serves UTF-8 file names

Tags: ftp, utf-8, vsftpd

I run vsftpd 3.0.3 / armv7l / Debian 9.11 / Kernel 4.14.133+

Some paths have Greek characters.

In file `/etc/vsftpd.conf` there is a line `utf8_filesystem=YES` but, also, this is the default behavior.

In client's charset autodetection mode:

Chrome, Opera, Total Commander understand that paths served with UTF-8 characters.

Firefox, FileZilla, Double Commander don't understand that paths served with UTF-8 characters and display 2 characters per Greek character. If I force charset to UTF-8, all work fine.

I am not sure that this erroneous behavior is client-side. I believe(!) that non-erroneous clients, just have a fail-safe mechanism on charsets.

It is a minor problem, but client-users other than me, can be frustrated.

Bellow is the Filezilla log, of connection:

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.1.2:21...
Status: Connecting to 192.168.1.2:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Command: AUTH TLS
Response: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Command: AUTH SSL
Response: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command: USER videos
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS 
Response: 230 Login successful.
Command: SYST
Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Command: FEAT
Response: 211-Features:
Response:  EPRT
Response:  EPSV
Response:  MDTM
Response:  PASV
Response:  REST STREAM
Response:  SIZE
Response:  TVFS
Response: 211 End
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,2,204,166).
Command: LIST
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,2,73,251).
Command: LIST -a
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

And an image with, how appear file paths:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileZilla needs the server to return `UTF8` in the response to the `FEAT` command to use UTF-8 automatically.

Your server does not return `UTF8`. But what is strange is that vsftpd 3.0.3 should return `UTF8` unconditionally. This is vsftpd 3.0.3 code for sending a response to the `FEAT` command:

```c
void
handle_feat(struct vsf_session* p_sess)
{
  vsf_cmdio_write_hyphen(p_sess, FTP_FEAT, "Features:");
  if (tunable_ssl_enable)
  {
    if (tunable_sslv2 || tunable_sslv3)
    {
      vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " AUTH SSL\r\n");
    }
    if (tunable_tlsv1)
    {
      vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " AUTH TLS\r\n");
    }
  }
  if (tunable_port_enable)
  {
    vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " EPRT\r\n");
  }
  if (tunable_pasv_enable)
  {
    vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " EPSV\r\n");
  }
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " MDTM\r\n");
  if (tunable_pasv_enable)
  {
    vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " PASV\r\n");
  }
  if (tunable_ssl_enable)
  {
    vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " PBSZ\r\n");
    vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " PROT\r\n");
  }
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " REST STREAM\r\n");
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " SIZE\r\n");
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " TVFS\r\n");
  vsf_cmdio_write_raw(p_sess, " UTF8\r\n");
  vsf_cmdio_write(p_sess, FTP_FEAT, "End");
}
```

That does not match the log you have posted. You must have some custom build of vsftpd or there's some proxy/firewall on the way that strips the `UTF8`.

---

Anyway, you can configure FileZilla to use UTF-8 always. On *Site Manager*, go to *Charset* tab and select *Force UTF-8*.

Comment: Indeed! Very interesting. I must upgrade to 3.0.3-2 (which is not available in my repo) https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=804777